# UITableView: why doesn't programmatically selecting and tapping to select play well together

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a button that selects all the cells. so when its tapped I basically run

```
for (int i=0; i<self.myDataSource.count; i++) {
    NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];        
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:tmpIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    [self.tableView.delegate tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:tmpIndexPath];
}
```

and that works great in that all the cell's UI updates correctly and whatnot.

But now when I try and tap on a cell (which I assume will mean I'm now deselecting it, since i selected it programmatically) instead the `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method is called so to the user it looks like "nothing is happening" since it goes from selected to selected. Tapping it a second time will now properly trigger the `tableView: didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method.

It seems like programmatically calling to select the cell isn't actually selecting the cell. The only reason the UI updates is because I manually call the `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Does calling `[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:tmpIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];` not actually select the cell in a way that can be recognized by the default tap to select? Does anyone know what's going on here?

Note: I have multiple selection enabled so I don't think this is a problem.

*More details*: I decided to check whether the cell was selected at two points. First I check directly after my call to `selectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:tmpIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
if ([[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:tmpIndexPath] isSelected]) {
    NSLog(@"Supposedly selected... right");
}
[self.tableView.delegate tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:tmpIndexPath];
```

this returns as true and prints to the console.

Now if instead I check whether the cell is selected using in the `didSelect...` method that is triggered when I tap on a cell, it will return false. This is despite JUST programmatically setting it as true, and confirming that its state was selected.

Somewhere, somehow the cell is being "deselected" internally without triggering any of the delegate methods.

Comment: Is `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` ever called? You could set a breakpoint in that method, and look at the stack trace to see why it's getting deselected.

Comment: it's not. I have tried setting breakpoints on willDeselect and didDeselect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was happening. At some point in my code there was a call being made to reload the table view: `[self.tableView reloadData];`. That method seems to clear the selection state of the cells, while preserving the selection UI for visible cells without calling any of the delegate methods for `willDeselect` or `didDeselect`.